# Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400

Tags: puppet

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Pupp\
et::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource typ\
e vcsrepo at /etc/puppet/modules/ansible/manifests/init.pp:74

Getting the above when running puppet agent --test --verbose.

The manifest includes

include vcsrepo-installer
  include ansible

This is so that I can bootstrap Ansible and get rid of Puppet once and for all.

While I can do a

puppet apply init.pp

manually, it works fine, but when it is part of the

puppet agent --test --verbose

it fails.

If any more information is needed, don't hestiate to ask.

Comment: Do you have the vcsrepo module installed ?

Comment: Yes puppet module list shows it. But it does not get included in the run of the module which contains the vcsrepo {} call.